# Filter array in array and get only the filtered items

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have the following array named filters and try to filter it by selected items.
At the end I want to have all filters where a selected item is, but only with the selected items

```
let filters = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'property',
    items: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: 'x',
        isSelected: false
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'y',
        isSelected: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'property2',
    items: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: 'x',
        isSelected: true
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'y',
        isSelected: false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to get the following array at the end:

```
let filteredFilters = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'property',
    items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'y',
        isSelected: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'property2',
    items: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: 'x',
        isSelected: true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried the following code, but it does not work.

```
let filteredFilters = filters.filter(filter => {
    return filter.items.filter(item => {
       return item.isSelected === true;
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `map` + `filter` since you're dealing with a nested array:

```js
let filters = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'property',
    items: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: 'x',
        isSelected: false
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'y',
        isSelected: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'property2',
    items: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: 'x',
        isSelected: true
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'y',
        isSelected: false
      }
    ]
  }
]


let filteredFilters = 
    filters.map(
        ({items, ...rest}) => ({...rest, items: items.filter(item => item.isSelected)})
    )
    .filter(x => x.items.length > 0);

console.log(filteredFilters);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I've been working on this the whole night, and now there are so few lines of code. But with your code I still get a filter object back if all items of a filter are not selected.

Comment: @Leon you need one additioanl filter - see my modified answer

Comment: I can't thank you enough. You saved me many more hours. Now I can take my time and check how the functions work.