# How we can achieve this Filter in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, filter

How we can achieve this Filter in Swift.

I have exactly same problem and i am trying this way and i found [this solution on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056650/filter-array-in-array-and-get-only-the-filtered-items)
but this is written in Javascript and i need code in Swift language.

Getting this error

> Cannot convert value of type '[Model]' to closure result type
> 'GetModel'

My Code and Model

```
extension Array where Element == GetModel{
    func matching(_ text: String?) -> [GetModel] {
        if let text = text, text.count > 0{
            return self.map{
                $0.data.filter{
                     $0.name.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())
                }
            }
        }else{
            return self
        }
    }
}
// MARK: - GetModel
struct GetModel: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    var data: [Model]
}

// MARK: - Model
struct Model:Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    var isSelected: Bool? = nil
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to return a different type, namely `GetModel`? Why not simply return an array of `Model`s?

Comment: i want to return [GetModel] but do not know how to do it.

Comment: Also, what does `GetModel` actually represent? Is it guaranteed that all `Model`s in the `data` array have the same `id` and `name` as the `GetModel` instance itself?

Comment: I am trying to implement search functionality like Apple contacts search have sections like A,B,C but when we try to search we can see the results without section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making two mistakes. First you are using `map` but you should be using filter. Second you are using `filter` when you should be using `contains(where:)`. Note you can. use `localizedStandardCompare` instead of lowercasing your string.

Note: You shouldn't check if your string count is greater than zero. String has an isEmpty property exactly for this purpose.

> To check whether a collection is empty, use its isEmpty property
> instead of comparing count to zero. Unless the collection guarantees
> random-access performance, calculating count can be an O(n) operation.

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Element == GetModel {
    func matching(_ text: String?) -> Self {
        guard let text = text, !text.isEmpty else { return self }
        return filter { $0.data.contains { $0.name.localizedStandardContains(text) } }
    }
}
```

---

edit/update:

If you need to filter your `GetModal` data:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Element == GetModel, Self: MutableCollection {
    func matching(_ text: String?) -> Self {
        guard let text = text, !text.isEmpty else { return self }
        var collection = self
        for index in collection.indices {
            collection[index].data.removeAll { !$0.name.localizedStandardContains(text) }
        }
        collection.removeAll(where: \.data.isEmpty)
        return collection
    }
}
```

Comment: @ZainAnjum Do you need to filter the GetModal data ? It is not clear if you want GetModel object with all data or only the ones that matches the criteria

Comment: I need [GetModel] array that matches nested array name